# Growling Scraping noise when driving

Tags: ford, noise, f-150, frontend

I have a 2012 Ford F150 4wd that has a growling scraping noise coming from what sounds like the front drivers side. I have changed the wheel bearing on the drivers side thinking that was the issue it wasn't, I have also changed the brake pads and calipers on both drivers and passenger side. Still have the issue what else could be causing the noise? The sound occurs most at speeds of 20-40 I'm sure it still is there at highway speeds just not as noticeable. The sound seems to stop when I turn. The only parts I haven't changed are the cv axle shaft and the rubber brake lines going to the caliper. I almost sounds like a brake dragging but I just do not know anymore. I also feel a slight vibration in the front when driving at highway speeds.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Does the sound change if you shift to a lower gear while maintaining the same road speed?